# Onclick alert window.show

Tags: javascript

I have this text, and i would like to display it in an alert that pop in the window. Do you know if it's possible to do so? Or there is a different way to do so?

(the text is in french)

```
<script>
function Vovo() {
alert("Bienvenue dans l’interface Voyager 

         Ici, vous allez pouvoir transférer vos données en quelques clics et en un temps record.




        Pour utiliser cette interface :


        - Sélectionner vos données

        - Cliquer sur le bouton décompression ce qui va vous permettre d’obtenir une clé

        - Grâce à cette clé, vous pourrez accéder à vos données depuis tous types de médias (ordinateur, Smartphone, tablette) ayant l’interface Voyager            




        Pour accéder à vos données :


        - Entrer la clé dans la case associée 

        - Cliquer sur décompression 

        -  Vous venez de récupérer vos données réelle et sans perte");
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't support multiline strings (until EcmaScript 6). Use `\n` instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: If I saw an alert like this, I would never visit your site again lol. I sure hope this is not a crucial way of displaying data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible, you just need to escape your newlines with `\n` (basically instead of using line breaks in your code, you will need to use `\n`.

Your output should be something like

`alert("Bienvenue dans l’interface Voyager \n\n Ici, vous allez pouvoir transférer vos données en quelques clics et en un temps record.\n\n\n\n\nPour utiliser cette interface :\n\n\n- Sélectionner vos données\n\n- Cliquer sur le bouton décompression ce qui va vous permettre d’obtenir une clé\n\n- Grâce à cette clé, vous pourrez accéder à vos données depuis tous types de médias (ordinateur, Smartphone, tablette) ayant l’interface Voyager            \n\n\n\n\nPour accéder à vos données :\n\n\n- Entrer la clé dans la case associée \n\n- Cliquer sur décompression \n\n-  Vous venez de récupérer vos données réelle et sans perte");`

If that looks like too much of a mess, you can also use string concatenation to preseve the look of your text in code.

```
alert("Bienvenue dans l’interface Voyager \n" +
"\n" +
" Ici, vous allez pouvoir transférer vos données en quelques clics et en un temps record.\n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"Pour utiliser cette interface :\n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"- Sélectionner vos données\n" +
"\n" +
"- Cliquer sur le bouton décompression ce qui va vous permettre d’obtenir une clé\n" +
"\n" +
"- Grâce à cette clé, vous pourrez accéder à vos données depuis tous types de médias (ordinateur, Smartphone, tablette) ayant l’interface Voyager            \n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"Pour accéder à vos données :\n" +
"\n" +
"\n" +
"- Entrer la clé dans la case associée \n" +
"\n" +
"- Cliquer sur décompression \n" +
"\n" +
"-  Vous venez de récupérer vos données réelle et sans perte\n");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now i'm having a little problem. When i view this text from my android, it shows ? at some text character such as ' é

Comment: You may need a meta tag defining the character set being used. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_charset.asp